# Does G-d immediately grant the requests of Gentile church attenders?

Tags: tefilla, gentiles, king-solomon

Follow up to this [M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/96941/5275).

King Solomon requested that G-d immediately grant the requests of Gentiles that come to pray at the Temple. For Jews, as I understand, synagogues have replaced the Temple.

Can we say the same thing about places of worship for Gentiles? Do churches, mosques, etc. act as equivalent substitutes for the Temple where a Gentile can come to pray to G-d and would G-d fulfill their requests according to the exact conditions that King Solomon expressed (i.e., whether they deserve it or not)?

I'm particularly interested in whether this condition would apply to Christians that believe in the Trinity and pray in a church. My understanding is that King Solomon's wishes implies that those that came to the Temple believed in monotheism. According to many opinions that I have read (I think Ramba"m is one such opinion), the Trinity involves the concept of *shituf* ("partnership) and is thus not considered monotheism. Thus, perhaps, with this condition, those that follow this belief would not have their requests immediately granted.

Comment: How did you go so far with this conclusion, the original question spoke explicitly of Bet Hamikdash to show G-d's affection of the Jewish people, but how did you connect that with churches?

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely not.

Hashem's name is not even associated with a shul to the same extent it was with the Beis Hamikdosh.

In no way or form is Hashem's name associated with a Church that He should grant prayers said there in order to save the honor of His great name.

Besides this, if their prayers aren't answered they can blame it on the other 2/3rds of the trinity.

Comment: Love that snark at the end, @user6591